# Nivo Slider Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, nivo-slider

I researched this site and tried a few things I found and I still am broken on this.
My website is [www.autofxcollision.com](http://www.autofxcollision.com) and the dots of the slider disappeared, and it puts a large gap under the picture pushing my words all the way down the page.  When I was testing it using dreamweaver through Chrome it worked fine, then when I uploaded I got that. I tried disabling one of the Javascript links, and adding the width to the wrapper of the slider...can someone please look at my code and see if I forgot anything.  Thanks a million

Jessica

Comment: It's autosizing to your largest image (the ford green tudor) - make all your images the same size and it will work properly (also that image is very large and could do with optimizing for the web)

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with nivo slider.. you have images which are in variable resolution.. Try to keep all the images in same resolution to achieve better result...

when i checked i saw a picture which has the height very large.. exactly till the white space...